# Gentoo + VICE (commodore 64 emulator)

Tags: linux, gentoo, commodore

Well, this is awkward. I've installed VICE on Gentoo (Commodore 64 emulator), and... can't start it. I've looked into distfiles and I should have "x64" as a starting command (also a bunch of others programs) but there is no such thing.

Here are the USE flags, which I have:

```
app-emulation/vice-2.4.22 alsa gtk ipv6 lame nls png sdlsound threads vte zlib
```

Any advice ?

Comment: I would definitely check on the gentoo forums. In my past experience they are really helpful

Comment: I did it on my local gentoo forum but so far no answers, I've tried everything to just start it, checked the install scripts, checked the bugtracker, checked official documentation and nothing. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it. It's in /usr/games/bin/x64

Answer (score 0):

This question, and the answer, ultimately solved my problem, but in reading the question, I think the author may have had the same *underlying* issue, unknowingly, which could have also been solved *unknowingly*.

I installed Vice, and initially, could not identify what command to run. A quick internet search lead me to this question.

Once I found the binary, I tried to run it directly, and got "permission denied". I quickly realized I was not in the "games" group.

Once in the "games" group, I simply had to restart my terminal emulator (or for better results, log out of my GUI session, and back in).